# Order of instances in Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-auto-scaling

When I use AWS CLI to query the composition of some Auto Scaling group (via [describe-auto-scaling-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html#describe-auto-scaling-groups)) I get the list of running EC2 instances: is the order of the instances consistent among runs? How are they sorted?

Comment: Neither the awscli operation nor the underlying API request document any specific ordering.

Comment: @Don, From my personal experience the order is consistent and it;s oldest first and newest last.

Comment: @Riz, we had a case in which the autoscaling group terminated an instance (which was in the middle of the list) and created a new one; this was placed at the beginning of the list

Comment: @Don, We have 10+ autoscaling groups and I checked them 'all' and I can confirm you are right. You can use `aws autoscaling describe-scaling-activities --auto-scaling-group-name myAutoscaling-autoscaling --region us-xx-1 --max-items 2`. In this case, The new ones are in the begining according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-verify-scaling-activity.html